# innerHTML adding scripts causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

This is my function that I'm using to add script for TeX:

```
function change() {
        var format = document.getElementById("format");
        var original_text = document.getElementById("question");
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('type', 'math/tex; mode=display');
        s.value = {x};
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = s.toString();
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
```

But this shows an error as `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: change`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: can you paste in the code where you have called this function?

Comment: `s.value = {x}`? Maybe you wanted `s.textContent = x`?

Comment: Why not just `newDiv.appendChild(s)` instead of trying to use `.toString()`?

Comment: s.textContent = x gives same

Comment: newDiv.appendchild(s) also returns same error.

Comment: `{x}` is not correct JSON. I would expect it would get to that line and reject the entire function, which is why it's not being found. What are you trying to accomplish with the line `s.value = {x} ?`

Comment: I want to add a TeX format string like `<script type=​"math/​tex;​ mode=display">​{x}​</script>​`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what my problem was. It was just the wrong way I was converting or rendering a MathJax script in a html page. It should be fixed like this:

Adding another script:

```
<script>
  //
  //  Use a closure to hide the local variables from the
  //  global namespace
  //
  (function () {
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
    var math = null;                // the element jax for the math output.

    //
    //  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
    //
    QUEUE.Push(function () {
      math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput")[0];
    });

    //
    //  The onchange event handler that typesets the
    //  math entered by the user
    //
    window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
      QUEUE.Push(["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"]);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Then it can easily be converted like this:

```
<p>
Type some TeX code: (Example: \int\sin{x}\;{dt})
</p>
<input id="MathInput" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" onchange="UpdateMath(this.value)" />
<p>

<div id="MathOutput">
You typed: ${}$
</div>
```

Output looks like:

[image]

Thanks to @DemoUser for his valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is rejecting this line:

```
s.value = {x};
```

The brackets are for <s>[JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://www.json.org/)</s> Javascript's object literal syntax. It is expecting you to finish with a hashmap, something like this:

```
s.value = {x: 'someValue'}
```

The closing bracket in yours is unexpected. What you *actually* want, though, is a string. The fact that the string means something special to LaTex is just a coincidence as far as Javascript is concerned:

```
s.value = '{x}';
```

Whether this accomplishes your ultimate goal remains to be seen, but if it doesn't then you'll probably need to open a separate question. Happy coding <3

Comment: The brackets are __not for JSON__, please read the article you've linked.

Comment: @Teemu Curly bracket, string, colon, value, end-curly bracket. Looks like the notation for an object in Javascript to me. I feel like you're trying to make a fine semantic distinction, probably because it's not stringified for message passing. Perhaps you should explain.

Comment: The JSON grammar is used to translate a String describing a set of ECMAScript objects into actual objects. When you describe an object literal in source code, this is exactly what happens, you're typing a string which the interpreter translates into an actual object. That interpreters accept non-standard JSON in the source code is another matter. Also, I see no reason not to apply the Duck Rule when helping a beginner.

Comment: Again: [JSON is not JS](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset). It's `JSON.parse()` which parses JSON, and a JavaScript interpreter parses JavaScript. You've linked to an article about language independent data-interchange format, which is totally irrelevant to OP's issue. If the JSON would have originally been named to DIF, you most likely wouldn't have linked to that article. What comes to Duck Rules, do you think it's fair to confuse a newbie even more by using misleading terminology? Btw. `{x}` is totally valid JS, not as an right-hand assignment though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably wanted to do something like:

```
function change() {
    var format = document.getElementById("format");
    var original_text = document.getElementById("question");
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'math/tex; mode=display');
    s.innerHTML = "{x}";
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.appendChild(s);
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Calling the `change()` function adds a `div` with script tag at end of `<body>` tag, as:

```
<div><script type="math/tex; mode=display">{x}</script></div>
```

Comment: Everything is happening except the script is not running. :/

Comment: @AbhishekDe can you be more clear on "script is not running" ..!

Comment: The script should produce a x in italic as it should appear in LaTeX format. But I see nothing appended. Although replacing it by an alert('Hello') does the job.